# Ionic 2 Facebook login

Tags: facebook, ionic2

I found this code:

```
login() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.facebookLogin().then((success) => {
            alert(success.access_token);
        }, (error) => {
            alert(error);
        });
    });
}


facebookLogin() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + "CLIENT_ID_HERE" + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&response_type=token&scope=email", "_blank", "location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes");
        browserRef.addEventListener("loadstart", (event) => {
            if ((event.url).indexOf("http://localhost/callback") === 0) {
                browserRef.removeEventListener("exit", (event) => {});
                browserRef.close();
                var responseParameters = ((event.url).split("#")[1]).split("&");
                var parsedResponse = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < responseParameters.length; i++) {
                    parsedResponse[responseParameters[i].split("=")[0]] = responseParameters[i].split("=")[1];
                }
                if (parsedResponse["access_token"] !== undefined && parsedResponse["access_token"] !== null) {
                    resolve(parsedResponse);
                } else {
                    reject("Problem authenticating with Facebook");
                }
            }
        });
        browserRef.addEventListener("exit", function(event) {
            reject("The Facebook sign in flow was canceled");
        });
    });
}
```

I am a bit confused, how does Ionic 2 app recognizes when user is signed in with some social apps like facebook/google?
For example, I want to make a landing page, which prompts for facebook login, and as soon as user is logged-in, dont show the page.
I am familiar with nodejs+passportjs which stores session/cookies, but how Ionic 2 it does?

Comment: Source of your code does not seem to be from Driftyco / Ionicframework.
Prehaps you should have a look at: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/facebook/
Or provide info on source project you are refferencing the code sinppet above. Looks like parsing some login respons in Cordova InAppBrowser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ionic Native's NativeStorage plugin to store user preferences. It keeps the data until the app is uninstalled.

Find more about it here:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/nativestorage/

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to integrate Facebook authentication Ionic app:

1. Implement any Facebook authentication using Javascript

   - CordovaOauth
   - etc.
2. Ionic Native

**Ionic Native** is a curated set of ES5/ES6/TypeScript wrappers for Cordova/PhoneGap plugins that make adding any native functionality you need to your Ionic, Cordova, or Web View mobile app easy.
 - Facebook: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/facebook/

Page provides all details needed to implement native Facebook authentication in your Ionic app.

Hope this helps answering your question and concerns.